# HTML Mileage Calculator won't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, email, variables, calculator

I have the HTML/Javascript code for a mileage calculator but the click to email link doesn't work properly. When I press the link in the webpage the email opens correctly but in the body of the email instead of displaying the calculated mileage it says 'undefined'.

Could someone please tell me the code I need to write to fix this problem and where to put it. Thank you.

My code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionDisplay;
    var map;


function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: copenhagen
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        }
    });
    }
    </script>

    <title>Distance Calculator</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 50%;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />

                <label for="end">End: </label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
            </p>
<a href="mailto:enquiries@syedasadiq.co.uk?subject=Mileage&body="
   onclick="this.href += calcRoute('string', 'distance');"
>
Click to send email
</a>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>

javascript google geolocation maps
```

Comment: Where does calcRoute return its value?

Comment: I don't know. People keep telling me that that's the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Will explain in an answer ...

Comment: You should have had a return statement at the end of your function, but there is a more fundamental issue that I've described related to the way you're using the Directions service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to rethink your code slightly. You are calling calcRoute when the click happens, but unfortunately you're dealing with an asynchronous service. The process that you have at the moment is:

- User clicks the hyperlink.
- calcRoute is called.
- The start and end points are retrieved into a request.
- The request is sent asynchronously to the Google DirectionsService.
- Your function finishes without returning a value
- 'undefined' is appended to the mailto link
- The browser trigges the mail client
- ... time passes ...
- *The asynchronous method completes, and populates the distance.*

The problem is probably a bit more obvious here: you need to alter your code to ensure that the distance has already been looked up by the time that the link is clicked. I'd suggest that the 'calculate route' button triggers this process, and then all the mailto: link needs to handle is appending the already-calculated distance. You should also disable the mailto: link while this calculation is in progress.

A quick note as well - the code as written will append the distance again if the mailto: link is clicked more than once. You may want to address that one at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you please tell me the code I need to write for this to work.

Comment: Is there any code I need to write, or does the whole script have to be re-written?

Comment: You don't have to rewrite the script, you just have to play around with the order in which various parts are triggered. I could rewrite it for you, but (a) I don't have the time to test it, (b) you wouldn't learn as a developer, and someone else writing the code wouldn't help you. I hope I've given you sufficient feedback in order that you are able to go back and have another stab at it yourself now.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't write the javascript, only the HTML, so as a result I don't understand exactly how it works.

Comment: I would really appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: Let me know who to contact with my hourly rate, and I'd be happy to.

Comment: I'm not here to write people's code for them; I do that for a living. I'm here to help developers.